# Integrating multiple javascript applications

Tags: javascript, integration

we are developing a new application using javascript framework which contains multiple module functionalities. Our org contains multiple teams and each team works on one module. At the end, we need to integrate all these modules related code into a single application and also may have navigations from one module to the other. Is there any way we can achieve this, like developing applications for each module seperately and integrate them as needed in such a way we can create various jar files and add it to a java application as a library.
Please suggest.

Comment: This may be similar to developing multiple projects in an application as multiple WAR files deeveloped in an EAR file.

Answer (score 0):

How about using some version control system (svn, git,..) to get everybody an updated copy of others teams work (I would recommend trying to use [svn externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html)), and [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) or [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) to integrate all modules on the fly?

Comment: The main intention here is to allow everyone develop their own modules as small applications and inject the code like an archive into the master application.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at MEAN, the backend is not in Java, but maybe you can modularize your frontend like they do http://mean.io.